# Python - String Formatting (How to Limit Decimal Without the Float Getting Converted Into String)

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10).reshape(5,2), index =['a','b','c','d','e'], columns = ['one', 'two'])

convert_decimal = lambda x: '{:.1f}'.format(x)

df = df.applymap(convert_decimal)

df
```

> Error: TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   ----> 1 abs(df)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in **abs**(self) 
>   1498     1499     def **abs**(self):
>   -> 1500         return self.abs()    1501     1502     def **round**(self, decimals=0):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in abs(self)
>   9480         3    7   40  -50    9481         """
>   -> 9482         return np.abs(self)    9483     9484     def describe(self, percentiles=None, include=None, exclude=None):
>
> TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please paste your full code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the above code it works fine

Comment: Check the working code https://www.ideone.com/NZfSO2

Comment: @Sheri try to convert the df to abs using abs(df).

Comment: what actually you are trying to please add clarity and more details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could just cast the lambda computation as a float.